# Chef - recipe concepts

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I've came across this recipe file and cannot understand many of its aspects, like:

```
Chef::Log.info ("Some log message")

  _jvm_index = "jvm_plan"
  _jvm_check = "id:#{jvm.plan}"

  data_bag = search(_jvm_index,_jvm_check)
  data_bag.each do |data_bag_item|
    l_author = data_bag_item['owner']
    l_neros = ldata_bag_item['deployment_actions']
    l_neros.each do |l_run_list|
      l_check = l_run_list['action']    
      v_type = l_run_list['action_on']['app_type']
```

1. What does the colon(:) mean here: `id:#{jvm.plan}`?
2. `data_bag = search(_jvm_index,_jvm_check)`
   is `data_bag` an array, if so, what does `search` do here and are `_jvm_index` and `_jvm_check` array values?
3. With respect to the line `l_author = data_bag_item['owner']` and `v_type = l_run_list['action_on']['app_type']` what exactly is done here?
4. What is the purpose of `['owner']` and `['action_on']['app_type']`?

I checked the Chef documentation for any explanation on this front but couldn't find anything unfortunately. I'm not sure whether I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: You should first read and understand chef concepts then it won't be difficult to understand. chef has good documentation for every resource, for example for your databag question you can go through https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html and see what's the purpose of databag and how it been used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The colon is used in Lucene searches (which powers Chef Search) to separate the key (facet) and value query expression.
2. Yes, `search()` returns an array. The other two values are above, you can see them yourself.
3. Data bag item objects can be used like hashes, so that is how you extract data from them.
4. See above.

Comment: Thanks a ton.. w.r.t the point 3 , can you please point me to any examples or a tutorial link where I can see the data format like above or how to construct that format - `v_type = l_run_list['action_on']['app_type']`

Comment: Sorry, I don’t actually understand your question. The code you are looking at is very bad Ruby and I’m guessing it was written by people that are primarily Java or C++ developers.

Comment: I wanted to know `v_type = l_run_list['action_on']['app_type']` what is `['action_on']` and `['app_type']` basically is and how can I construct that format.. any link to understand better of those.. Im really sorry for the badly shaped Ruby code.. 
Thanks really for your time here

Comment: Those are invoking the `Hash#[]` operator, which is how you retrieve keys from a Hash.